# How to type pound sign(£) using US keyboard, in Windows, Linux and Mac?

Tags: keyboard, currency-format

I have dual boot configuration with Fedora and Windows XP. Keyboard is normal US standard keyboard. Now that I am working for a UK based client, I need to use pound sign quite often. Currently I am copy pasting it, and it is a bit annoying. If it is possible to type pound sign using US keyboard, then that will be great. Please post any method you know other than copy pasting.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

For US Keyboard:

- Windows:

  1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> (on numpad with Num Lock on)
  2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+ (numpad)</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>
- Linux:

  1. <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> / <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>
  2. <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>(hold down) then
     <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>

To enable Windows 2., set the registry key`HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method\EnableHexNumpad` to `1 (REG_SZ)` and reboot.

Comment: I have tested Windows and Linux (fedora) and it works fine. But I couldn't test this in Mac. Please test and post comment below. Thanks

Comment: I'm on a Mac. It works

Comment: On Linux you could enable a compose key and then: <compose> + L + = should give you £.

Comment: @Dennis, the hex version for Windows doesn't work for me; just gives a ♥ (as though `Num+` and `a` did nothing)

Comment: @NickT: Forgot a *minor* detail.

Comment: @muffinresearch: I'm pretty sure you mean <compose> + L + -.  <compose> + L + = creates the Lira sign (₤), not the pound sign (£).

Comment: On Ubuntu, I had to do CTRL-SHIFT u0a3

Comment: Is there an option to use `Alt+` codes on Windows when you don't have a Numpad (e.g. on a Bootcamp MacBook)?

Comment: I'm on a laptop which does not have a number keypad.  What can I do?  Using the normal numbers does not work.

Comment: @Flimzy for pound instead of Lira you should use lowercase L: AltGr+`l=` gives same result as AltGr+`L-`.

Comment: what if my keyboard doesn't have a numpad?

Comment: The second solution for Linux didn't work for me. The first did once I realised that in GNOME the apparent default for Compose is Shift+RightAlt and you have to let them go before typing the L and -.

Answer (score 25):

On Windows and Linux, use the "U.S. International" keyboard layout, which is [US with additional modifiers and characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_US-International.svg) used abroad. The £ is on `RightAlt+Shift+4`.

You can also get £ on Windows by entering `Alt+0163` or `Alt+156`.

---

On Mac OS X, simply press `Option-3` for £, or use the British layout, where £ and # are exchanged (`Option-3` and `Shift-3`). Otherwise, they're very similar (check with Keyboard Viewer).

Comment: *RightAlt+Shift+4* is not helping me. *Alt+0163* is working in windows. I haven't checked in Linux.

Comment: It is not working in my Fedora installation

Comment: `AltGr+Shift+4` is indeed the correct combination for the U.S. International layout, and I can confirm that it works: £££££££££££

Comment: @JdeBP On Linux?

Comment: I typed that on Windows NT 5.0.  Linux is harder to test this on, let alone access the WWW from, where I am right at the moment.  But you can always ask [Diederik Willemsen](http://dry.sailingissues.com./us-international-keyboard-layout.html) to confirm the same instead.

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks. I knew the Windows behavior, but had to search for how Linux behaves. Your link confirms my sources. I'd have to guess it's somehow dependent on the window manager or something else WarFox doesn't have.

Comment: WarFox said that xe hadn't checked in Linux.  So presumably it is on Windows NT that `AltGr+Shift+4` was "not helping".

Comment: @JdeBP The second comment. Fedora is the former RedHat Linux.

Comment: On Ubuntu for the RightAlt+Shift+4 sequence to work select ¨English (US, International with dead keys)¨ in Settings -> Keyboard Layout

Comment: Further to my previous comment using a compose key is probably easier than using a dead key enabled keyboard layout. Especially for programmers. Having to press space after hitting ' to get a single quote would need quite some getting used to.

Comment: That US Intenational keyboard is annoying as when you type a quote character it waits for another key before typing anything. This allows you to compose weirder characters but if you're just looking for the odd pound it's a steep price to pay.

Comment: BEWARE! Even though it works on Windows `£`, this is going to screw up your quote `' "`, tilde `~` and some other keys because `United States-International` layout has modified characters enabled and waits for a second character after aforementioned key press to produce characters like  `á é í ó ú` etc. So to get single or double quote you need to press it twice. Really annoying.

Comment: on my keyboard "RightAlt+Shift+4" worked for me to get the £

Answer (score 3):

On a European keyboard on Linux type `AltGr + Shift + 3`.

You can always find it out by greping the keyboard layout config files under `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/*` for `sterling`.

Comment: Works on Polish layout.

Answer (score 0):

I can't manage to have my sterling sign associated with my keyboard command. It's a Portuguese Brazil ABNT2 layout (set to Portuguese (Brazil) language). In Windows, it works easily by using CTRL + ALT + 4, but tried all combinations for Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) and just can't make it work.

Difficult situation for a Brazilian accountant in the UK haha

---

-----> **SOLVED** (by trial and error lol)

altGr + shift + 4 = ¼
altGt + Tab + 4 = ££££

yaaaay (the bad thing is that everytime I press tab it moves to the next cell)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 11/10 on a US laptop keyboard, you have the following options:

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to show the emoji panel, then find the `£` symbol in there (may be on a different tab if you haven't used it recently)
2. Switch your keyboard setting to `ENG UK` (using <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) and type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>
3. Switch your keyboard setting to `ENG INTL` (using <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) and type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

If you have a keyboard with a separate numeric keypad (I don't), you can supposedly use the following:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+(keypad)<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+(keypad)<kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>

(Mac and Linux have been well answered by [the answer above](https://superuser.com/a/293129/181356).)