# Pound sign on Windows on MBP with US keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a MacBook Pro (early 2011 model) with a U.S. keyboard, which of course does not have a number pad.

I have Windows 7 installed on a second partition using Boot Camp. How can I insert the GBP Pound (currency) sign using the keyboard alone? (I don't particularly want to have to go into Character Map.)

Answer (score 3):

I am not a huge expert on this, but one thing you could do is download the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665) and create your own keyboard layout, and Map Shift+3 (or whatever else you want it to be) to the Pound sign. This tool can be pretty handy, you get complete reign over your keyboard layout. This **won't** affect your Mac OSX install since it is just particular to the Windows installation, it doesn't reconfigure the laptop keyboard or anything like that.

Comment: Ahh, this sounds like a pretty good suggestion! Will try it out, thank you. If there's anything slightly less overkill perhaps, still interested to hear it though.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the british keyboard layout and then press Shift-3 if i remember correctly.

Comment: Using the British keyboard layout messes up other shortcuts and keys too though...

Comment: But that is kind of a easy way out. Alternatively you can use autohotkey to assign a hotkey to put the pound symbol... but that's more labor intensive than [alt-shift][shift-3][alt-shift] if you only need the pound sign occasionally. if you need it more than occasionally... may as well really use the autohotkey

Comment: Thanks. Autohotkey looks like an interesting problem. Does it actually have to switch between keyboard layouts though?

Comment: i think you will send the unicode character directly with it.

Comment: Has anyone tested whether AutoHotKey can detect the Fn key on the MBP keyboard? That would allow us to add a new function to every key on the keyboard except the F keys.

Answer (score 1):

[As already discussed on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/293119/), using the [U.S. International keyboard layout that comes supplied in the box with Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306560), the pound sign is <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.  [According to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1220), this is thus <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> on the MacBook Pro keyboard.

Comment: I saw that, and I'm afraid neither of those combinations work on my MBP. I am using the `United States (Apple)` layout and also tried the `United States - International (Apple)` layout.

Comment: Those aren't Windows keyboard layouts.  It is _Windows_ that needs to be configured with the U.S. International keyboard so that AltGr+Shift+4 produces the pound sign.

Comment: Using the normal (non-Apple) U.S. International layout messes up other keys though, like `~`.

Comment: Turning it into a _dead key_ to add tildes to characters isn't really "messing up".  And it's not hard to type a space immediately after typing the dead key to get an ordinary non-combining tilde.

Comment: It doesn't add tildes to characters... it outputs gibberish. :P